# Removing randomly generated file extensions from .jpg files using python

Tags: python, regex, bash, scripting, batch-rename

I recently recovered a folder that i had accidentally deleted. It has .jpg and .tar.gz files. However, all of the files now have some sort of hash extension appended to them and it is different for every file. There are more than 600 files in the folders. So example names would be:

```
IMG001.jpg.3454637876876978068
IMG002.jpg.2345447786787689769
IMG003.jpg.3454356457657757876
```

and

```
folder1.tar.gz.45645756765876
folder2.tar.gz.53464575678588
folder3.tar.gz.42345435647567
```

I would like to have a script that could go in turn (maybe i can specify extension or it can have two iterations, one through the .jpg files and the other through the .tar.gz) and clean up the last part of the file name starting from the . right before the number. So the final file names would end in .jpg and .tar.gz

What I have so far in python:

```
import os

def scandirs(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for currentFile in files:
            os.path.splitext(currentFile)

scandirs('C:\Users\ad\pics')
```

Obviously it doesn't work. I would appreciate any help. I would also consider using a bash script, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: You seem to be on windows; I doubt you want a bash script to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.move(currentFile,os.path.splitext(currentFile)[0])`

at least I think ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, using regular expressions:

```
import os
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^(.*)\.\d+$')


def scandirs(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for currentFile in files:
            match = pattern.match(currentFile)
            if match:
                os.rename(
                    os.path.join(root, currentFile),
                    os.path.join(root, match.groups(1)[0])
                )

scandirs('C:/Users/ad/pics')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) I will give you an answer that will remove the last extension for all files/directories in a directory:

```
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

Comment: would i be running this in the current directory?

Comment: @TendekaiMuchenje Yes